# How do I reverse changes in the terminal

Tags: command-line

I am a newbie trying to fix a problem and ended up typing `video=Svideo-2:d` into the terminal, I am worried that I changed something I shouldn't have changed. How can I change it back?

Answer (score 1):

If you typed that into the terminal, then you just set a environment variable called "video" to the value "Svideo-2:d". This will not cause anything (just when a program reads this variable), it will not be permanently (after a reboot it will be away). You can type

```
unset video
```

to delete this variable now.

Comment: It gets away just with closing the shell too. Variables aren't shared between shells.